# swift: SnapKit in swift doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, snapkit

When I change main navigation controller(view controller.swif) to profileviewcontroller.swift my

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    createTop()
}
```

my `createTop()` in profileviewcontroller.swift function can't add something to `self.view`. And when I write import "Sn" (when I want to write SnapKit) word Snapkit is strikeout.

Comment: Xcode can be funny, have you tried just manually entering `import SnapKit` and seeing if it compiles ok?

Answer (score 1):

make sure SnapKit library appears both on `Embedded Binaries` and on `Linked Frameworks and Libraries` on your **Project Settings** > **General**

You will probably be able to use `snp` namespace even without adding `import SnapKit`